# How to calculate the difference between 2 columns in 2 separate tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following 2 tables with expenses and incomes by month:

[income table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OjFR.png)

[expense table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Eyvi.png)

I'm having a hard time calculating the information `income - expense` (profit) for each month,

The result should be another table like this:

[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVIbA.png)

What is the best way to accomplish this ?

For context, the tables of the datasource are not grouped by month and year, these are only the grouped by sum, these tables have a many to many relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Date/Calendar table that will act as a Dimension to your two "fact" tables. I'm assuming you have a date column in both of these two tables.

You can create a Date/Calendar table by creating a Calculated Table with the following:

```
DimDate = 
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Year", FORMAT([Date], "yyyy"),
    "Month", FORMAT([Date], "MMMM"),
    "Month num", MONTH([Date])
  )
```

Once created, click on the `Month` and do a `Sort by column` on `Month num`.

Then create relationships from this new Date table to your two table (One-to-Many, single direction), looking like:
[image]

Once you have this, the rest is easy. Create the following measures:

```
$ Income = SUM('Income'[income])

$ Expense = SUM('Expense'[expense])

$ Profit = [$ Income] - [$ Expense]
```

That's it. Ensure you use the columns from the Date table in visuals with these measures (and not the dates from the "fact" tables).

Comment: Saw this Dimension Date table in other articles but didn't quite understand the purpose of it, I assumed they were a part of the databases but now it makes sense.

I was unaware of this trick, worked like a charm, thank you very much.

Comment: Better to do this as m-formula than join tables as measure... `= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "DatePeriod", each Date.FromText([Month]&" 1, "&Text.From([Year])))`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new query and you could probably leverage this. Make sure the table names you have match the inputs and you should get a single table with both inc and expenses. Both must have same year/month count format.

```ml
let
    //whatever your table names and column are...
    zIncomeTable = Inc_TBL, 
    zExpenseTable = Exp_TBL,
    zYearColName = "Year",
    zMonthColName = "Month",
    
    startTable = Table.NestedJoin(zExpenseTable, {zYearColName, zMonthColName}, zIncomeTable, {zYearColName, zMonthColName}, "Inc_TBL", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    newTable =  Table.ExpandTableColumn(startTable, "Inc_TBL", {"income"}, {"income"})
in
    newTable
```

Ultimately it's joining/combining tables.

Answer (score 0):

First bring expense from 2nd table to 1st table using `LOOKUPVALUE` calculated column

[image]

Then write a calculated column to find the difference between Income and Expense

[image]